# ITunes not showing iPad apps

Tags: itunes, ipad

After latest iTunes (11.0) upgrade there is no sidebar where devices are supposed to appear. How do I rearrange the apps on my iPad2 via iTunes now?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the top right you'll see iPad when it is plugged in.  click on that - then it will take you to the page you want.

You can also go to the View menu and select "Show Sidebar" and you'll have all the same choices on the left that you had in previous versions of iTunes, if you prefer that interface.